# .htaccess rewrite does not work with adwords gclid passed to the final url

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Have a problem with traffic coming from Google Ads.

A have a redirect roll that redirects

```
https://example.com/some-words-words-aktivitet/
```

to

```
https://example.com/index.php?mobile=1
```

(`RewriteRule ^some-words-words-here//?$ ?mobile=1`)

Now when I have the URL that includes `gclid` I need to pass that value to the final URL like this.

```
https://example.com/some-words-words-aktivitet/?gclid=some_value
```

to

```
https://example.com/index.php?mobile=1&gclid=some_value
```

How do I do that?

I have tried this with no success.

```
RewriteRule ^escape-room-teambuilding-aktivitet/\?gclid=([^/]*)/?$ ?mobile=1&gclid=$1
```

Comment: The rule you've processed is an internal rewrite (as it should be), not a "redirect" (as you've stated), so I'm wondering where the problem is here... Google Adwords processes the request using JS and if this is an internal rewrite then the `gclid` is still present in the visible URL that Adwords sees. (?) Adwords does not see the rewritten URL that contains the `mobile` URL parameter (and no `gclid` param) since this is entirely internal to your server. (?)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^escape-room-teambuilding-aktivitet/\?gclid=([^/]*)/?$ ?mobile=1&gclid=$1
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string, so the above will never match.

`([^/]*)` is also the wrong regex to use here since this is part of the query string, where parameters are delimited by `&`, not `/` (as in the URL-path).

You could probably just use the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag to append the original query string from the request to the *substitution* string. This will include the `gclid` parameter, but will also include any other URL parameters. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^example/$ index.php?mobile=1 [QSA,L]
```

Note the addition of `index.php` in the substitution string. Your original directive is reliant on mod_dir. And the `L` flag to prevent further processing.

This would rewrite a request of the form `/example/?gclid=somevalue&foo=bar` to `index.php?mobile=1&gclid=somevalue&foo=bar`.

---

#### Alternatively...

If, however, you wanted to target the `gclid` URL parameter only (and discard all other URL parameters) then you would need a separate *condition* and check against the `QUERY_STRING` URL parameter. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(gclid=[^&]+)?
RewriteRule ^example/$ index.php?mobile=1&$1 [L]
```

This would replace your existing rule since it handles URLs both with and without the `gclid` URL parameter.

This would rewrite a request of the form `/example/?gclid=somevalue&foo=bar` to `index.php?mobile=1&gclid=somevalue`. And `/example/?foo=bar` to `index.php?mobile=1&` (the trailing `&` is inconsequential).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule ^some-words-words-here//?$ ?mobile=1
> ```

This doesn't match the stated example URL (so make sure you are editing the correct rule!). The trailing `//?$` is also a bit odd. This is the same as simply `/$` (a trailing slash is mandatory) because multiple contiguous slashes in the URL-path are *reduced* in the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. You are also missing the `L` flag, so the outcome is unpredictable if you have other directives that follow. (And, as mentioned above, you should be rewriting directly to `index.php`, not relying on the `DirectoryIndex` (mod_dir)).

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite unfortunately your solution did not work :-(

Comment: @user3699041 After writing my answer I'm a bit confused as to what problem you are trying to solve here (hence my comment below your question). Ordinarily `gclid` is a URL parameter read by client-side JavaScript, so any internal rewriting of the request (as I assume you are doing here - not a "redirect") should not affect this to begin with. So, I'm wondering if there is something else going on here? Please update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file and the actual URL being requested. Are you doing something with the `gclid` parameter server-side?

Comment: @user3699041 _Aside:_ Strictly speaking you shouldn't _need_ to include the `gclid` parameter in the rewritten URL anyway, since this could be parsed from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP superglobal. I am assuming you are not externally "redirecting" the request (as you have erroneously stated in your question)?